# Django ORM - Group by and annotate with subquery

Tags: python, django, orm

What I'm trying to do in Django ORM is the following:

- Group by user
- Sum the profits
- Annotate with the latest status of that user

My queryset looks like this:

```py
Sales.objects.values('user').annotate(
    profits = Sum('profit'),
    status = Subquery(Status.objects.filter(username=OuterRef('user')).order_by('-date').values('status')[:1]
).order_by()
```

If I inspect the SQL query of this queryset, I can see that the `status` field is added to the `group by` clause. But this query cannot be executed. How can I prevent Django from adding this to the `group by` clause? Because the rest of the query just works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a User object rather than a Sales object.

I don't know your model structure, so this is a bit of a guess.

```
User.objects.annotate(
    profits = Sum('sales__profit'),
    status = Subquery(Status.objects.filter(username=OuterRef('user')).order_by('-date').values('status')[:1]).order_by()
```